# Analysing questions posted on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support

I want to write an app which analyses questions posted on stack Overflow. Using number of questions posted for a  particular language, we may determine how popular it is.

My questions are

1. Is this legal?
2. Does Stack Overflow provides any such APIs to fetch data programmatically?

Comment: see api.stackexchange.com

Comment: Voting to leave open. Although the question mentions SO, it is relevant for any site on the SE network.

Comment: What's wrong with using SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer)? There are already hundreds of queries that explore popularity of language tags. That's https://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And one more: this question looks like a dupe...

Comment: Nothing wrong, just that I am new here and not aware of such options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Is this legal?

Yes, as long as you follow the Stack Exchange [Network Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) and [APIs Terms of Use](https://stackexchange.com/legal/api-terms-of-use)

> 2. Does Stack Overflow provides any such APIs to fetch data programmatically?

Yes, please visit: http://api.stackexchange.com/. Please note that there is a '[Rate Limit](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle)' set in order to prevent abuse the Stack Exchange API implements a number of throttles.

Also, as pointed by Deer Hunter in his comment:

> What's wrong with using SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer)? There are
> already hundreds of queries that explore popularity of language tags. That's [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/)